# can a CMD line parameter be re-defined

Tags: batch-file

I am looking for how to re-define the last parameter of a CMD line as null during execution of the batch file. My attempts to re-define %n, where n is the last parameter, as null have failed

Batch file a.bat

```
@echo 1=%1 2=%2 3=%3 4=%4 5=%5
set %%5%=""

@echo 1=%1 2=%2 3=%3 4=%4 5=%5
set %%5%=

@echo 1=%1 2=%2 3=%3 4=%4 5=%5
```

Result

```
a one two three four five


1=one 2=two 3=three 4=four 5=five

set %5=""

1=one 2=two 3=three 4=four 5=five

set %5=

1=one 2=two 3=three 4=four 5=five
```

`%5` does not change

Comment: consider the parameter variables `%1` etc as "read only". To do what you describe, you have to use normal environment variables `set fifth=%%5` and later `set fifth=newValue`

Comment: Firstly, we have no idea if any variables have been `Set`/`Defined` at all. If you've inexplicably decided not to post that part of your script, then please note that you should not use numeric variables, _(or certainly not those which begin with them)_. For example, the command processor will not know if `%2nd%` is a variable named `2nd` or a string `twond%`, this will inevitably end in tears. When it comes to `Set`ting variables, you should use this syntax, `Set "VariableName=Variable Value"`, so to un-`Define` one, you'd use, `Set "VariableName="`.

Comment: @compo: johan is speaking of parameters (and clearly mean it, judging by his code example), not variables. (you were probably confused by `echo 1=%1 ...`, as was I for a few seconds)

Comment: That may well be the case, @Stephan, but it wasn't **clear** to me, and in order to change the values, they would generally need to `Set` variables, and use those instead. If that were the case, the advice I've provided in my comment is still valid.

Comment: I'm curious why you think you need to clear the definition of `%5`. I suspect there are simple solutions that don't involve clearing `%5`.

Answer (score 2):

If you only have `5` arguments, you could un-`define` the fifth, *(last)*, one using `Shift`, *(enter `shift /?` at the Command Prompt for its usage information)*. This would effectively move the empty/un-`defined` value of `%6` to the position of `%5`.

Example:

```bat
@Echo Off
Echo 1=%1 2=%2 3=%3 4=%4 5=%5
Shift /5
Echo 1=%1 2=%2 3=%3 4=%4 5=%5
Pause
```

If you wanted to `Set`/re-`define` a parameter/argument to another value then you could do so by using a `Call` statement:

Example:

```bat
@Echo Off
Echo 1=%1 2=%2 3=%3 4=%4 5=%5
Call :Sub %1 %2 %3 %4 cinco
Pause
GoTo :EOF

:Sub
Echo 1=%1 2=%2 3=%3 4=%4 5=%5
Exit /B
```

Other than this you have little other choice but to `Set` your arguments/parameters to variables, then re-define them as required:

Example:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "one=%~1"
Set "two=%~2"
Set "three=%~3"
Set "four=%~4"
Set "five=%~5"
Echo one=%one% two=%two% three=%three% four=%four% five=%five%
Set "five=cinco"
Echo one=%one% two=%two% three=%three% four=%four% five=%five%
Pause
```

Comment: +1 - You could improve your SHIFT solution by adding a `:clearArg5` label, followed by `if "%~5" neq "" (shift /5 & goto :clearArg5)`.

Answer (score 0):

"I'm curious why you think you need to clear the definition of %5"

An added parameter will affect operation of a long used script if it is present. The actions of the script are based on the content and number of parameters in the CMD line.

I want to add a prefix to the script which detects a parameter of 'test' to set a variable of test="@echo ", then delete 'test' to prevent the script detecting a parameter error or behaving incorrectly.

The script will be modified to prefix each 'action' line with %test%. The script will run as-is when there is no test parameter, and when present it will let me build a set of use cases which can be used to explain what the script does.

Thanks for the assistance, SHIFT /n where n is the last parameter will do what I need.